# Reconstruct view scoped bean by navigationHandler

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, liferay

I use NavigationHandler#navigationHandler for redirect to other page, but in moment when it fires invoked init() method (@PostConstruct). Why?

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) throws IOException {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("JSF : QuestionnaireListBean : onRowSelect(SelectEvent event)");

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().put("questionnaireId", selectedQuestionnaire.getQuestionnaireId());
    NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, "/views/questionnaires/viewDetails.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true&questionnaireId=" + selectedQuestionnaire.getQuestionnaireId());

    System.out.println("JSF : QuestionnaireListBean : onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) time = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ViewScoped` bean will not survive any GET-requests, even to the same page.

It will only survive Ajax and POST-requests while staying on the same page.

I suspect you're in need of a `SessionScoped` or `ConversationScoped` bean.

Comment: Yes, but i don't use this bean on target page. Why it's init?

Comment: Is it a dependency of any other bean you're using on the target page?

Comment: No, target page bean does not contains any injection or dependency.

Comment: Does this occur only on redirection to that particular page or any page?

Comment: This occur only if i use NavigationHandler#navigationHandler. In case using ExternalContext#redirect() or by default <h:link /> it does not occur.